# Отправка нескольких фото одним сообщением в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Сейчас бот принимает и пересылает только одно фото в чат, как сделать чтобы он принимал несколько фото, которые отправил пользователь одним сообщением и отправлял их также одним сообщением в чат?

```
                if 'photo' in json_data.get('message', {}):
                    photo_file_id = json_data['message']['photo'][-1]['file_id']
                    user_state[user_id]['photo_file_id'] = photo_file_id
                    problem_message = '\n'.join([f"{key}: {value}" for item in problem for key, value in item.items()])
                    user_state[user_id]['problem_message'] = problem_message
                    markup = buttons()
                    bot.send_photo(chat_id=message_data['chat_id'], photo=photo_file_id,
                                   caption=f'Обращение от {message_data["first_name"]} ({message_data["from_user_id"]}):\n{problem_message}',
                                   reply_markup=markup)
                    bot.send_message(message_data['chat_id'], 'Отправить обращение?')
                    user_state[user_id]['step'] += 1
```

Comment: вы можете использовать метод `send_media_group` для отправки локальных файлов или файлов по ссылкам, а если требуется просто переслать сообщение другому пользователю или в группу/канал можно использовать `copy` или `forward`